# How to reconstruct an image that has been divided into several pieces?

Tags: python, function, matrix, puzzle

I'm trying to write a code which gets the pieces of an image, that are represented by an `m X m` matrix. two pieces belong together if the right side of the matrix of one piece is the same as the left side of the other piece, these two pieces should be "glued".

I wrote the function join which joins two pictures together, I started writing the puzzle solving function but I got stuck and I don't know how to continue.

```
def join_h(mat1, mat2):
    """ joins two matrices, side by side with some separation """
    n1,m1 = mat1.dim()
    n2,m2 = mat2.dim()
    m = m1+m2+10
    n = max(n1,n2)
    new = Matrix(n, m, val=255)  # fill new matrix with white pixels

    new[:n1,:m1] = mat1
    new[:n2,m1+10:m] = mat2
    '''
    #without slicing:
    for i in range(n1):
        for j in range(m1):
            new[i,j] = mat1[i,j]

    for i in range(n2):
        for j in range(m2):
            new[i,j+m1+10] = mat2[i,j]
    '''
    return new

def reconstruct_image(m):
    matlst=getlistmatrix()
    for i in range(len(matlst)):
        if matlst[i][i]==matls[i+1][i+1]


def getlistmatrix():
    matrixlst=[]
    for i in range(1,1601):
        matrixlst.append(Matrix.load('./im'+str(i) +'.bitmap'))
    return matrixlst
```

Comment: In what way are you stuck?  What is the next problem you are trying to solve?  What did you try and what happened?

Comment: @dg99 I can't figure out how to start reconstructing the puzzle, how do I choose which piece to start with and how I get the edges.

Answer (score 0):

*scikit-learn* library provides you with the function 'reconstruct_from_patches_2d' - *sklearn.feature_extraction.image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d*

If you know the order of the overlapping blocks, then you should be able to use this.

Refer: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d

An example provided by them for the same - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_image_denoising.html#example-decomposition-plot-image-denoising-py